# GNOME Shell Global Menu Extension broke my GTK

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I've been playing around with the GNOME 3 Shell and like it very much so far.

But I've installed an extension that provides application menu pushing to the topbar. I think it's a great idea to allow the user to choose where she does want to see her menu.

However there's a bug in that extension: whenever I turn it off – my menu disappears. It's now just nonexistent so I can't really *File > Quit* or anything like that.

So I'd like to know how to repair my GNOME now. I've tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell
```

… but no success, no output.

P.S. it's called global menu extension, the `deb` package is in official Ubuntu repositories, so it's called `gnome3-globalmenu`.

Comment: thx for the edits

Comment: `rm /etc/profile.d/globalmenu.sh` did the job. It exported a GTK_MODULE and the uninstaller forgot to remove that
I've found that by looking the contents of a `deb` package

Comment: For the time being, I've edited your question to highlight the solution. Please post an answer with the solution so we have correct Q&A format! :)

Comment: @iglvzx that's exactly what I wanted to do, but "users with less than 100 repo can't post an answer to their own questions for 8 hours"

Comment: I see. Well, everything looks good here now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm /etc/profile.d/globalmenu.sh` did the job. It exported a GTK_MODULES appendix 
I've found that by looking the contents of a `deb` package